An everyday expression for "to dilute something with two/three/four/etc. times its volume of water"

Dilute the juice with three times its volume of water. [my sentence]

My intuition tells me that native English speakers would not use this sentence in ordinary conversation. What would you say in ordinary conversation instead of this?
The Japanese language has an everyday expression that means to dilute something with two/three/four/etc. times its volume of water, but it seems that the English language does not have any.

Mix one part juice to three parts water.
That is the usage I have seen most often.

Thank you very much, Mary. Is it possible to say Mix one part juice with three parts water?

Yes, that's another way to put it.

+1. Or "one part syrup to three parts water by volume" (picking syrup rather than juice as the result would be different there)

Note: If your instructions are for people in the US, measurements are done by volume unless specified otherwise.

I don't think there is any special way of saying this in English. Your example sentence is acceptable. Equally possible is

Dilute the juice 1 to 3 with water.

You might say that this is ambiguous, but any native speaker would know you meant 3 parts water to one of juice and not the other way round.
Then, to quote a humorous song "Bright College Days" by Tom Lehrer, there is

Three parts gin to one part vermouth.

If it's something like orange squash, in the UK the instructions would just say "Dilute to taste" and leave it up to you.

My mother used to say 'show the vermouth bottle to a glass of gin'.

I think you could also say “Dilute the juice with three parts water” — or, if the juice was already the subject, merely “Dilute with three parts water” — which is concise and unambiguous.

@Peter Jennings. Thank you very much. Is it possible to say "Dilute the juice with water 1 to 3" instead of "Dilute the juice 1 to 3 with water"?

@Kaguyahime Yes that would work too. This is an instance where word order in English is flexible and any native speaker would understand and find it normal.

"Dilute" is a perfectly good word to use in casual conversation. Yes, a chemist might use it in a technical journal article, but it's also used in ordinary conversation.
You could also say "water down" if you're mixing it with water. Like, "Water down the juice."
"Mix with water" is also possible.
Are you looking for a word that says how much water? I mean like, "Double the size" says not only to make it bigger, but to make it twice as big? I don't know of any English words that means to dilute by a specific amount. You can say, "Mix with 3 units of water for each unit of juice". There's no word for "mix" or "dilute" that implies 3 to 1, or any other specific ratio.

Another colloquial term for "dilute" is to "cut" something, although it may indicate a non-specific amount.

@NuclearHoagie I've only heard "cut" used in connection with illegal drugs, like "to cut cocaine". Maybe some use it in a broader context.

Agree there can be a sense of "adulterate" connoted with "cut", usually done with the purpose of making something less strong. I've also seen it in the context of cutting whiskey, or too-sweet juice, with water.

@NuclearHoagie Personally I don't recall ever hearing someone say they "cut juice with water". Not saying you're lying, just that it's not something that people in circles I move in say. Perhaps it's a regionalism, perhaps sub-culture, etc.

We speak less of diluting one thing with another, and more of mixing the two in a given ratio.
To be clear, one certainly could say to dilute the juice with water, and after mixing the two I might say that the juice "has been diluted", that's just not really the "everyday expression" that you're looking for.
Usually, I wouldn't say that I'm "diluting" the juice with water. I would say that I am mixing water and juice. To state the amount of water and juice, state the ratio. The order of the ingredients needs to match the order of the numbers in the ratio. For your example:

Mix one part juice with three parts water.
Mix one part juice to three parts water.
Mix three parts water with one part juice.
Mix three parts water to one part juice.
Mix water with juice 3-to-1.
Mix juice with water 1-to-3.
Make a three to one mixture of water and juice.
Mix juice 1-to-3 with water.
Mix water with juice, three parts to one.

Any of those should be understood, but I would go with the first or second one. I would mention "parts", and I would tend to say the smaller part first. You can use either "with" or "to" as the preposition, it's not important.
At least here in America, liquid is measured by volume, not weight. I would never imagine that those parts are measured in weight unless explicitly told so.

The shortest natural way to say it is "Dilute the juice in three parts water", meaning one part ingredient to three parts water. I would take this to mean measurement by volume, but it's ambiguous.
This is also written "dilute 1:3 with water", pronounced "1 to 3".

In a scientific context you could say "make a two-fold, three-fold or ten-fold dilution" (diluting up to 2,3, 10 times the volumes respectively). The use of -fold has not been common in general use for a hundred years or more.

In some contexts, "make a half/quarter strength dilution" or "diluting to half/quarter strength" should also be well understood.
